# Java GroupBy with 3 classes and Enum

Tags: java, group-by, stream

I'm a beginner in Java.I have an issue that I can't seem to solve.

I have 3 classes,

```
public class Pet {
public String petname;
Type type; }

public class Owner {
public String name;
public int age; }

public class PetStore {
public Owner owner;
public ArrayList<Pet> pets;}
```

my output is right now:

```
Owner Mike (39) owns the animals: [Cat: Sunny, Rat: Bean, Cat: Milk, Dog: Boomer]
```

But I want a different output, like this:

```
Owner Mike (39) owns the animals: [Cats: Sunny, Milk], [Rat: Bean], [Dog: Boomer]
```

How can I achieve this? Can I use Stream and groupBY?

-------------- Edit ---------------------

I have a Program Class where I generate random data. I want to user the groupBy with the Petstore List.

```
public static List<PetStore> getAllAnimal(){

    return petstore = IntStream.range(0, 20)
            .mapToObj(i -> new PetStore(new Person(getOwnerName(),getOwnerAge()), new ArrayList<Pet>(getList())))
            .collect(toList());
}

public static ArrayList<Pet> getList() {
    int randomSize = 1 + rand.nextInt(5);
    return animals = IntStream.range(0 , randomSize)
            .limit(randomSize)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Pet(PetNameGenerator.getName(), rand()))
            .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And what is you code actually ?And what is class `Type`

Comment: Type is an Enum: enum Type { Cat, Dog, Rat, Hamster , Fish; }

in my Program class I generating a list : List<PetStore> petstore , and I have two methods

Comment: public static List<PetStore> getAllAnimal(){

        return petstore = IntStream.range(0, 20)
                .mapToObj(i -> new PetStore(new Owner(getOwnerName(),getOwnerAge()), new ArrayList<Pet>(getList())))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    public static ArrayList<Pet> getList() {
        int randomSize = 1 + rand.nextInt(5);
        return animals = IntStream.range(0 , randomSize)
                .limit(randomSize)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Pet(PetNameGenerator.getName(), rand()))
                .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    }

Comment: everything is created randonly

Comment: @ProgrammerUnstable Please edit your question and add relevant information you provided in the comments, thanks!

Comment: @AlexRudenko sorry, i did it

Comment: For you know : when you add code, don't do it in commen, edit your initial post and format it properly ;)

Comment: @azro thanks :) i'll do it in the future

Answer (score 2):

Group by the pet's type and use `Collectors.mapping` to extract/map a Pet instance to its name and collect them as a list.

```
 Map<Type, List<String>> petTypeToNames = petStore.getPets()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pet::getType,
                Collectors.mapping(Pet::getPetname, Collectors.toList())));
```